# Using enum as template parameter C++

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, enums, instantiation

This is the code I am trying to compile. I have a .cpp file where I do the following:

```
typedef enum enumtags {
    ONE,
    TWO
} enumType;

template <class T> 
class example {
  public:
    example(int key, T value):
        key_(key),
        value_(value) {}
  public:
    int key_;
    T value_;
};

//Explicit instantiation since I have the template in a cpp file
template class example<enumType>;

//Now a template function in the same cpp file
template<typename T>
void examplefunc(int key, T value) {
     somefunction(example<enumType>(key, value));
}

//instantiation of the function for the types i want
template void examplefunc<enumType>(int key, enumType value);
template void examplefunc<int>(int key, int value);
```

This throws a compilation error on clang++. The error is "no matching constructor for initialization".
If I replace the enumType in the line "somefunction" with int or double, everything is fine and dandy. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Unscoped enums are implicitly convertible to `int`, but `int` isn't implicitly convertible to an unscoped enum type.

Comment: You probably want `example<T>` inside `examplefunc` (otherwise, you need an explicit conversion). Also, there's a `;` missing after the class template `example`.

Comment: @T.C. Could u elaborate a bit more..please

Comment: @Rama In `examplefunc<int>`. Inside that, you pass a `T = int` as value to `example<enumType>`, which expects a `T = enumType` (note this is a different T). So you ask for conversion from `int` to `enumType` which is not (implicitly) possible. dyp suggested in his comment to replace that call by `example<T>`. We don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but this looks like a reasonable fix which could fit your intent. Depending on what you wanted to do, an explicit conversion could be a solution, too: `example<enumType>(key, static_cast<enumType>(value))`

Comment: @leemes thanks for the explanation. dyp's suggestion worked. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Inherit enum from unsigned int. use this enum for template argument.

```
enum FooEnum : unsigned int
{ FOO1,FOO2};
template<typename EnumType> 
void FooUser(EnumType t){}
int main(){ 
FooUser<FooEnum>(FooEnum::FOO2); 
return 0;
}
```

Unusual trick but works!